# Does there exist any predefined Observer in Boost odeint for Cpp for all kinds of error handling and warning messages?

Tags: c++

Like solve_ivp or odeint in python, which shows warning messages if there arises any discrepancy during runtime, in Boost odint we need to create observer for that. I just want to know is there any predefined observer exist to handel all kind of errors and warnings message or we have to creat for our own?

I have checked in boost odeint there are odeint_error.hpp and exception.hpp, but they can't be used directly.